# When to bind data in asp.net custom server control

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, custom-server-controls

We have a number of asp.net custom server controls in our website solution. Most of these are class files that inherit from DropDownList, call a stored procedure, and bind to the results.  Now I'm trying to optimize them, but am having a difficult time figuring out the best place to do the work.

There goal here is to do the db queries ZERO or ONE time.

ZERO:
Some pages that have the custom server control on them actually end up hiding them on page load based on some variable. So, if I put the binding code in the page load (or page init) of the control, it fires even if the hosting page never displays it, and I'd like to not do the query work if it's not needed.

ONE:
So, I've experimented with doing the binding by overriding the RenderContents event in the control.  That seems to solve the problem in that if a hosting page hides the control, that event doesn't fire.  However, if the control *is* visible on the page, then it does fire and the control binds.  But... it also fires on every postback, and I only want to the db query once.  So, normally, on the first time through, I'd stash the DataTable in ViewState and then use that subsequently.

But my testing shows that if I set ViewState in the RenderContents method, then it doesn't seem to exist on subsequent postbacks (see code sample below). And the db lookup happens every time (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

I'm assuming that it's too late in the page event lifeycle for .NET to take note of it.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```
protected override void RenderContents(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        buildList();
        base.RenderContents(writer);
    }

    private void buildList()
    {
        DataTable dt;

        if (ViewState["data"] == null)
        {
            dt = GetData();         // assume this executes a stored proc on SQL Server and returns a DataTable of results
            ViewState["data"] = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["data"];
        }

        this.DataSource = dt;
        this.DataTextField = "Description";
        this.DataValueField = "ID";
        this.DataBind();
    }
```